# "Start on" vs. "start from" in context

Tags: prepositions

Can you please tell me if I have to use *start on* or *start from* in the context below.

> By signing up for this plan, you'll get unlimted data for 30 days **starting on** the day you sign up.
>
> By signing up for this plan, you'll get unlimted data for 30 days **starting from** the day you sign up.

Are both perfectly natural there? If so, which one is more common?

Comment: 'From' should be used undoubtedly because 'From' used to mean-when something starts...

Comment: Does the "day" count as part of the 30?  Is the plan working on that day? If so, "on" would be better. Saying "from" is slightly ambiguous as it could be argued that it starts the next day. ¶ There's a similar situation with "available *until* Wednesday" and "available *through* Wednesday". Compare with "The sidewalk will be replaced from my house to the corner". Does that include in front of my house? ¶ Generally if one way of saying something is easier to understand or less potentially ambiguous, that's the one to choose.

Comment: Either preposition (or *none at all*) is syntactically fine. But ***from*** is significantly more common - probably, as @Sam suggests, because it specifically denotes an ***origin / start*** (as opposed to ***to***, which denotes a ***destination / end***).